# Google Authorized redirect URIs

Tags: redirect, google-plus, google-oauth

Let's say my app's main domain is at https://www.example.com

App is going to have lots of instances, i.e.

https://www.example.com/client1

https://www.example.com/client2

https://www.example.com/client3

<..>

In order to have OAuth2 authentication against my app, I currently have redirect URIs as such:

https://www.example.com/client1/SignInGoogle

https://www.example.com/client2/SignInGoogle

Is there a way to add one Authorized redirect URI for all of these clients? i.e.

https://www.example.com/*

or

https://www.example/com/*/SignInGoogle

Or does this URI has to be the *exact* match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Google Developer console [image]

1. Must have a protocol (HTTP / HTTPS)
2. Cannot contain a URL Fragment  (#)
3. Cannot contain a relative path.
4. Cannot be a public IP address.

Examples of Relitve vs Absolute URIs

```
Relative URI    Absolute URI
about.html      http://WebReference.com/html/about.html
tutorial1/          http://WebReference.com/html/tutorial1/
tutorial1/2.html    http://WebReference.com/html/tutorial1/2.html
/                   http://WebReference.com/
//www.internet.com/ http://www.internet.com/
/experts/           http://WebReference.com/experts/
../                 http://WebReference.com/
../experts/         http://WebReference.com/experts/
./about.html    http://WebReference.com/html/about.html
```

What you want to do is something like a Relative URI.  What you need to remember is that an Authentication server is nothing but a web service.  If you cant access the redirect URI from a normal web browser the authentication server cant either.

So no you cant do that it has to match exactly.